# Do first-order phase transitions necessarily imply hysteresis?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

As an example of first-order transition with hysteresis, I am thinking of the magnetization of the subcritical Ising model as a function of the magnetic field. Or density in the liquid-gas transition where we have supercooling effect as the hysteresis loop.
Are there examples with a first-order transition but no hysteresis?

**Edit:** more detailed description of connections between first-order transitions and hysteresis is given here: [https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/NumericalMethods/PhaseTransitions/Lecture/pt3.html](https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/%7Ekrauss/Lectures/NumericalMethods/PhaseTransitions/Lecture/pt3.html)

Comment: Can you provide a reference where the relation between phase transitions and hysteresis is discussed? Is this discussion (see link) of any help? https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/NumericalMethods/PhaseTransitions/Lecture/pt3.html